# Join Two DataFrames While Preserving Index

Tags: python, pandas

Consider data frame:

```
asdf=pd.DataFrame({'a1':[True,True,True,False,False],'a2':[False,False,False,True,True],'p':['p1','p2','p3','p2','p3']})

 
      a1     a2   p
0   True  False  p1
1   True  False  p2
2   True  False  p3
3  False   True  p2
4  False   True  p3
```

I wish to create the data frame

```
      a1     a2 
p
p1   True  False 
p2   True  True
p3   True  True
```

Attempt at a solution: I have tried various permutations of "+", "pd.concat", and "pd.merge" (all attempts not shown for the sake of clarity):

```
print(asdf)
print('\n\n\n')
tmp1=asdf[asdf['a1']==True]
tmp1.set_index('p',inplace=True)
tmp2=asdf[asdf['a2']==True]
tmp2.set_index('p',inplace=True)
print(tmp1)
print(tmp2)
print()
print(tmp1+tmp2)
print()
print(pd.concat([tmp1,tmp2],axis=1,join='outer'))
print()
print(pd.merge(tmp1,tmp2,how='outer',on='p'))
```

However, this does not give the required result, i.e. there are multiple columns with same key values. Any suggestions or resources to consult? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.max()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html) to aggregate the True/False results of the same `p`, as follows:

```
asdf.groupby('p').max()
```

With [`GroupBy.max()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html) on the boolean, you will get the correct aggregation result of boolean:

`False` + `False` = `False`

`True` + `False` = `True`

`False` + `True` = `True`

`True` + `True` = `True`

**Result:**

```
      a1     a2
p              
p1  True  False
p2  True   True
p3  True   True
```

Comment: @gsandhu  Pleased to help!   :-)

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of `any`:

> Return whether any element is True, potentially over an axis.
>
> Returns False unless there is at least one element within a series or
> along a Dataframe axis that is True or equivalent (e.g. non-zero or non-empty).

```
>>> asdf.groupby('p').any()

      a1     a2
p
p1  True  False
p2  True   True
p3  True   True
```